# develop a Custom HTML Slider for joomla

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

I'm new to web and its developing.I have `HTML` code and `JS` & `CSS` codes snippets i want to grab all these into one HTML page to Attach `custom HTML page to Joomla`.  Please find below the link I followed.please help me. I need to use this kind of slider

[Click here to see i want to use  CSS,JS,HTML code](http://codepen.io/johnblazek/pen/nceyw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Instead of creating a custom HTML page for slider you can create a banner module,then assign it to a proper menu , this way has several advantages and you can use it on multiple Joomla sites and easy to manage etc.
In this method you can manage images from banner manager and links ,clicks,impressions etc. An example [Joomla banner slider](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-banner-slideshow-module) can be download form [here](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-banner-slideshow-module). If you have some experience in Joomla then it is very easy to make your slider from the example.

If you still want to use custom `html` create an article then assigne it to a proper page like home. Then use some [Sourcer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) kind of plugin for adding script inside article editor.

Hope it make sense..